# Handling Multiple Callback URLs for Facebook Webhooks in a Salesforce App

Tags: facebook-graph-api, salesforce, webhooks, instagram-api, apex

I'm developing an app integrated with Salesforce, where I intend to programmatically subscribe users to Facebook webhooks using Apex. Each user, upon providing their access token, will be subscribed to specific webhook events. My challenge involves handling webhook events in Salesforce, especially considering the need for different users to have distinct callback URLs.

For context, consider the following Instagram webhook data I expect to receive:

`{ "entry": [ { "id": "0", "time": 1700727363, "changes": [ { "field": "mentions", "value": { "media_id": "218730219730128308", "comment_id": "218379213792137" } } ] } ], "object": "instagram" }`

Given this data structure, there's no direct way to identify the user it belongs to, as the response doesn't include a user ID. This presents a significant issue when trying to direct the webhook event to the appropriate user's instance in Salesforce.

I'm exploring ways to authenticate users without solely relying on Salesforce's Auth Provider, open to suggestions if there are alternative authentication methods. Additionally, I'm looking for strategies to either:

```
Configure multiple callback URLs for a single Facebook webhook to direct events to the correct Salesforce instance based on the user, or
Identify the user associated with the Instagram event in cases where the webhook data does not include a user ID.
```

Are there any established practices, alternative approaches, or suggestions on managing multiple callback URLs for Facebook webhooks within a Salesforce app? How can I ensure that webhook events are accurately directed and processed for the corresponding user in the absence of a user ID in the payload? Or is there some other way so subscribed user can get there data to their own rest api or something.

This project encompasses several components, most of which I have successfully implemented. Addressing this particular aspect was reserved for the final phase of my development process. However, upon reaching this stage, I encountered this unexpected challenge that has led to the current predicament.

Comment: There is no way to configure more than one callback URL for any given product.

Comment: _"Given this data structure, there's no direct way to identify the user it belongs to"_ - the `id` certainly won't be `0`, and according to the documentation, it should contain the Instagram Business or Creator Account ID.